# C# code (which is generated for choice element with decimal and int in xsd schema) doesn't contain enum

Tags: c#, xsd

When I generate code for this xsd schema:

```
...
<xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
   <xs:element name="IntProperty1" type="xs:int" default="0"/>
   <xs:element name="IntProperty2" type="xs:int" default="0"/>
</xs:choice>
...
```

I got class with int property Item1 and Item1ElementName enum (contains AssessmntId and MaxScore values).
But for this:

```
...
<xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
   <xs:element name="IntProperty" type="xs:int" default="0"/>
   <xs:element name="DoubleProperty" type="xs:double" default="0"/>
</xs:choice>
...
```

Generated class contains object property Item1 and there is no enum.
What should I do to define what data is choosed (AssessmentId or MaxScore)?

```
Item1 is double
```

and

```
Item1 is int
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it by means of checking type of Item1 (is int, is double). It works fine